# FPGA to PC data transfer with PCI EXPRESS

Tags: fpga

I'm using the VC707 Fpga board which include a Virtex 7 Xilinx FPGA.
I want to transfer the Data from the DDR 3 memory to a PC via the PCIexpress.
Is there any tutorial that exist to do so?
I have been nreading this tutorial https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/vc707/2014_4/xtp207-vc707-pcie-c-2014-4.pdf
But it isn't that helpful
Thanks

Comment: Is that tutorial too simple or too complex for you?

Comment: It is probably to complex i don't really understand what are they trying to achieve. I don't see which data they are transferring from the FPGA to the PC

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some information, for example you don't tell us how the data gets into the DDR memory. I'll leave that for now.

You want to have an FPGA with DDR and PCIe. Both are very high speed interfaces and require a good understanding of electronics. You are using a commercial board so we can assume the board has been proven to work with DDR and PCIe.

You first need to make an FPGA with these interfaces. Thus you have to make a DDR block and and a PCIe block. Xilinx has done most of the work but you have to drive the tools to fill in the detail. That is what the tutorial is about.
Some Virtex-7 chips have a ready built PCIe block, but not all. What I have seen, none has a ready built DDR interface. There may be an similar tutorial how to make a DDR interface.

If you manage to work your way through that you have two individual blocks of logic. You then need the HDL skills to connect those up.

If you are lucky both blocks work. If, for some reason, they do NOT work the above mentioned knowledge of high speed interfaces and electronics must be applied as well as ho to debug an FPGA system.

Last but not least you have to write PCIe device drivers on your PC to access all what you have built.

My question about the tutorial was to assess your skills in FPGA and HDL. What you want to achieve requires experience and knowledge with FPGAs, HDL design and the Xilinx tools. If your have not worked with FPGA, HDL, Xilinx before you have two options:

- First spend a few weeks/month to get more experienced in those fields.
- Find somebody who has that experience already to do the most difficult work for (with?) you.